# Mnemonic for the names of all parshiot?

Tags: names, parsha-torah-portion, memory

Is there a mnemonic device (like an acronym, acrostic, notarikon, poem etc) to remember the Hebrew names of all the parshiot in the order they appear?

Comment: I think it's בנלוחתווומוושובבימתתכופוצשתמאקאבבבנבשקחבפממדוערשככנוהו but I don't think it's that popular.

Comment: @DoubleAA if you say it loud enough you'll always sound precocious

Comment: http://www.imamother.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=229748

Comment: The only acronym I know of that's somewhat "popular" is שובבי"ם which is an abbreviation of the six weekly parshiot from שמות through משפטים. It is a minhag to study the laws of *niddah* during this period

Comment: 1. In the Beginning 2.Noah went out and 3. He Saw (a lovely woman named) 4.Chaya Sarah (and married her). they had 5. Children who grew up and 6. Left... (from the artscroll biography of Rabbi Yosef Tendler)

Comment: At least the first half of Shemos we have שובבים (תת)